# How to access individual prediction in Spark binary classification

Tags: java, apache-spark

Similar to the Spark's manual, I'm using the following script to get the predicted result for my SVM classifier:

```
int numIterations = 100;
final SVMModel model = SVMWithSGD.train(train_parsed_data.rdd(), numIterations);

// Clear the default threshold.
model.clearThreshold();

JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Object>> scoreAndLabels =
test_parsed_data.map(
            new Function<LabeledPoint, Tuple2<Object, Object>>() {
                public Tuple2<Object, Object> call(LabeledPoint p) {
                    Double score = model.predict(p.features());
                    return new Tuple2<Object, Object>(score, p.label());
                }
            }
);
BinaryClassificationMetrics metrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(JavaRDD.toRDD(scoreAndLabels));
double auPR = metrics.areaUnderPR();
double auROC = metrics.areaUnderROC();
```

The result of the above script is the *scoreAndLabels* variable which is a (score,label) tuple where score is the result of classifier and label is the true label of the instance that Spark uses in order to ease the evaluation of performance metrics (precision, recall, etc). However, it seems that there is no direct way to find what label the classifier assigned to each sample in my test data and it seems that there is a built-in module somewhere inside the Spark core that uses the score to assign a label to each test sample. Therefore, it seems that the only thing that we can get from Spark is some performance metrics and we can't simply find the predicted labels if we use any binary classifier.

Is there is way to somehow find the predicted labels for our test dataset in Spark?

Comment: `predict` method does exactly what you want, doesn't it?

Comment: **predict** method returns the score which is the result of classification and it is a double-precision value. I think Spark uses a threshold value to decide how to assign a binary value to this double valued score. But still, if it is true, I'm not sure how to get that threshold value.